# Weblogic Parallel Applications Deployment

Tags: weblogic, web-deployment

By parallel applications deployment, I'm talking about getting rid of the **edit lock** error in Weblogic deployment.

```
[Deployer:149163]The domain edit lock is owned by another session in non-exclusive mode - 
this deployment operation requires exclusive access to the edit lock and hence cannot proceed.
If you are using "Automatically Aquire Lock and Activate Changes" in the console, 
then the lock will expire shortly so retry this operation. -> [Help 1]
```

I've done my research through google, stackoverflow and oracle itself and got nothing.

I believed AS powerful like Weblogic should have covered this feature,
could anyone help me out here?

**EDIT 1: **
I am doing deployment via some Ant scripts, so parallel deployment is really what i need.

**EDIT 2: **
I need to do parallel deployment via some automation like Ant or Maven, so unlock manually is really not my option...

Answer (score 11):

It seems previous modification of the configuration was not committed. It can happen if you modified the configuration e.g. through console but forget to commit.

Open the admin console (default - `http://localhost:7101/console`) log in. After successful login look in the upper left corner. There you see a button where you can activate pending changes (or revoke them).
Then retry the deployment.

Peter

Comment: I was talking about parallel deployment by some deployment script, say Ant or Maven or etc...

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem, with my nightly build deployments.

The documentation tells you to use nonexclusive deployment mode:

**usenonexclusivelock**

> Specifies that the deployment action (deploy, redeploy, stop, and so
>   on) uses the existing lock on the domain that has already been
>   acquired by the same user performing the action.
>
> This attribute is particularly useful when the user is using multiple
>   deployment tools (Ant task, command line, Administration Console, and
>   so on) simultaneously and one of the tools has already acquired a lock
>   on the domain.
>
> Valid values for this attribute are true and false. Default value is
>   false.

**Source:** http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13706/wldeploy.htm#i1022929

**Ant example:**
http://adfhowto.blogspot.de/2011/07/troubleshooting-domain-edit-lock-is.html

**weblogic.Deployer example:**

```
java weblogic.Deployer -debug -remote -verbose -name MyWebApp -source MyWebApp.ear -targets server1 -adminurl t3://localhost:7001 -user weblogic -deploy -stage -upload -usenonexclusivelock
```

Comment: In the Ant example, it described _*In other not to fail but exist gracefully leaving you deployment to be applied when the Lock is released*, then use `nonexclusivelock` option_ I rather like it gets pending until it finishes deployment or an error breaks it

Comment: Me too, but it seems it's the only option one can find for parallel deployments.

Answer (score 3):

Go to weblogic admin console say in localhost:7001 and in the left see if you have released the configuration , ie. 'Release Configuration' button is greyed or not. If not. click that and then try to redeploy from your IDE. That worked for me at least :) Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

Click on **Release Configuration** button (if showing in enabled mode) to release the lock. This solved my issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when i was trying to deploy application using wlst online script. My issue with the edit mode. I have used exclusive="true" in startEdit(). 
That is where my error occurred.